# Google Earth Engine export problems

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have the below code that on a short story calculates Leaf Area Index(based on work of Schiffman et al., 2008). When i want to export the LAI collection I transform it in a list to export all the elements of the list. I used this method  to export collection images in the past and it work as smooth as possible everytime.

The below code is for running the LAI script:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fgeorgeboldeanu20%2Fscripturi_bune%3ALAI_L8

Right now I have problems with the exports, it exports it into tiles
(2-3 maybe 4 tiles), it exports parts of the whole images(some are missing), it exports tens of small images that are emptyall fixed in size. Someone's been dealing with this issue lately??

I didnt find any answer for this, but i saw some google earth engine apps down, maybe there are some cloud issues?

Comment: You're asking two questions - you really should post them separately. When you export to drive, EE can tile the image for you. Look at `fileDimensions` in `Export.image.toDrive()` docs. I don't know what the default size is, so maybe these are the small tiles you're seeing. You also have the `skipEmptyTiles` options, which is `false` by default. Try setting this to `true`.

Comment: I edited to  have one question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export.image.toDrive` will break up large exports into tiles ([reference](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting#large-file-exports)). Your exports are unnecessarily large because the bounds for the image is being set by the extent of the Code Editor Map viewport because you have not provided a [`region` argument](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#export.image.todrive) to `Export.image.toDrive`. Define the region as the `.geometry()` of the image being exported. Additionally, your data are floating point (large file) - you could scale it by 100 and then convert to 16-bit to make the file size smaller.

```js
Export.image.toDrive({ 
  image: image.multiply(100).round().toInt16(), // <-- scale, cast to 16-bit
  region: image.geometry(), // <-- use the image geometry as the region to export
  description: name1,
  folder:'LAI',
  fileNamePrefix: name1,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13, , // <-- set to 1e13 - the max
  skipEmptyTiles: true,
  crs : 'EPSG:3844'
});
```

Comment: Thank you Justin. I really didn't knew the tilling procedure for big files. Even by now I exported some images. Everyday you learn something new I suppose. Stay safe!